# page not updating when adding shortcode and it is rendering the shortcode content in wordpress dashboard also during wordpress plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin for event slider , but when i add shortcode to display the slider the wordpress page editor doesnot update and it is also rendering the content in admin dashboard.
the error i am getting is "**Updating failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response.**"
[screenshot of updating failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxzY7.png)
**event-plugin.php file**

```
add_shortcode("myeventplugin","short_code_view");
function short_code_view(){
    include PLUGIN_DIR_PATH.'views/shortcode-template.php';
}
```

**shortcode-template.php**

```
<?php
$allevents=display_events_from_db();

?>
<div class="main-eps">
    <?php
    if (count($allevents)>0){
    foreach($allevents as $key=>$value){
    ?>
    <div class="eps-event-cards">
        <div class="img-cont">
            <img src="<?php echo $value['thumb'] ?>" class="event-thumb">
        </div>
        <div class="textcont">
            <a href="<?php echo $value['slug']; ?>"><p class="event-title"><?php echo $value['title'] ?></p></a>
            <p class="event-desc">
                <?php
                $aa=$value['description'];
                if (strlen($aa) >= 40) {
                    echo substr($aa, 0, 40)." ... ";
                }
                else {
                    echo $aa;
                }
                ?>
            </p>
            <p class="event-date">
                <?php
                $newDate   =   date("l M, d, Y", strtotime($value['date']));
                echo $newDate;
               ?>
            </p>


        </div>
    </div>
        <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Change your shortcode to

```
add_shortcode("myeventplugin","short_code_view");
function short_code_view(){
    ob_start();
    include PLUGIN_DIR_PATH.'views/shortcode-template.php';
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, the "return" on shortcode functions must be the content itself... there's no clean way to do this without using the output buffer.

Comment: Man, i love you! I've finally found the answer - THANKS :-)

Answer (score 0):

You forget add `return`:

```
add_shortcode("myeventplugin","short_code_view");
function short_code_view(){
    return include PLUGIN_DIR_PATH.'views/shortcode-template.php';
}
```

Hope help you.

Comment: @KhurramAnsari could you var_dump(display_events_from_db();) provide here?